# AWS create-rule AWS CLI giving error "Unknown parameter in Conditions[0]: "PathPatternConfig", must be one of: Field, Values"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to add a path pattern /images/* to an existing ALB listener rule. Following is the command that I have executed. Please note that the variables $listenerARN and $tgARN has correct values, which I have not shown here due to security reason.

```
aws elbv2 create-rule --listener-arn "$listenerARN" --priority 5 --conditions "Field=path-pattern,PathPatternConfig={Values="/images/*"}" --actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn="$tgARN"
```

When I execute the above command I get the following error:

```
Unknown parameter in Conditions[0]: "PathPatternConfig", must be one of: Field, Values
```

I get the same error if I provide the value for --conditions from the external .json file, which has the following content.

```
[
    {
        "Field": "path-pattern",
        "PathPatternConfig": {
            "Values": ["/images/*"]
        }
    }
]
```

I read the documentation several time and I am sure I am following the exact syntax, but I cannot get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use an alternate syntax for complex JSON here:

```
--conditions file://conditions.json
```